# Android 7.0 MediaCodec encode wrong color format

Tags: video, encoding, android-mediacodec, android-7.0-nougat

I used the code below to encode `video/avc` format from `Surface`

```
MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, width, height);
// ...
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
        MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
// ...
```

And use `MediaMuxer` to write to a `mp4` file.

But the output can't play with `MediaPlayer`, after a little analysis, I found the pixel format(color format) is very strange, see the output below from ffmpeg.

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7ffeba000000] decoding for stream 0 failed
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'VID20160901_112308_1180449004.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : mp42
  minor_version   : 0
  compatible_brands: isommp42
  creation_time   : 2016-09-01 03:23:15
  com.android.version: 7.0
Duration: 00:00:06.74, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1449 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m), 640x1136, 0 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 40:71, 0.01 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2016-09-01 03:23:15
  handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2016-09-01 03:23:15
  handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

The video stream has no `bit rate` with very low `frame rate`, and the pix format is `yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m)`, who can explain this kind of color format?

The same encoding code work prior Android 7.0, following is a workable output from Android 6.0.

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'files/video/VID20160901_171106_156925259.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : mp42
  minor_version   : 0
  compatible_brands: isommp42
  creation_time   : 2016-09-01 09:11:11
  com.android.version: 6.0.1
Duration: 00:00:04.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1498 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x1136, 1439 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 40:71, 28.87 fps, 29.83 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2016-09-01 09:11:11
    handler_name    : VideoHandle
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 44 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2016-09-01 09:11:11
  handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

The only obvious difference is the pixel format, I got `yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m)` in Android 7.0, but it should be `yuv420p`.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you find a way to solve it ? I have ta very similar issue (if not the same).